# store string values into object and use later

Tags: ssis, etl, script-task

I would like to store file names that are processing into variable? and then later using this variable (file names) to move these files into proccessed folder. I am using foreach loop where dataflow task process each file and storing file names into object in script task with in loop.

```
string filename = Dts.Variables["User::FILE_NAME"].Value.ToString();
object proccessed_file_name;
proccessed_file_name += filename;
Dts.Variables["User::FILE_NAME"].Value = proccessed_file_name;
```

Pls help me store string values into object and use later in the package.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without the script task and only 1 variable `User::FILE_NAME`.

Use the `foreach loop` on a directory, populate the `FILE_NAME` from that task.  Process the file via your Data Flow Transformation.  Then move the file. Then simply let your `foreach loop` continue.  By moving the files incrementally you will know exactly what has succeeded and what has failed and will be able to restart your process without having to rollback the files that were processed correctly and starting from scratch.

If you want to wait to move everything, you could do a 2 stage move.  1 in the same logic as above that simply renames to .processed or something at the original directory.  Then after that loop finishes add another `foreach` filtering to processed files then use same `FILE_NAME` variable and move your files.

No need for a `script task` in either situation.

If you really want to use a `script task`.  Put the `script task` after your `DFT` in your `foreach loop`.  Have another variable that is `object` type which will hold a `datatable` or something.  Populate that `DataTable` with the file name etc.  Then after your `foreach` you will need `another script task` that will load the table and get the file name you want to process.  Honestly at that last step it is easiest to use `system.io` and move the files within the script.

How would you use the Variable that is a `datatable` something like (and I am writing this freely so this will likely need additional steps and error checking.)

To Populate File Names into `DataTable`, make `File_Name` variable readable, and `DataTableVariableName` read/writeable to the script task then start with something like:

you may actually have to test for null of user `variable.value` before this line I am not positive.

```
system.data.datatable dt = (system.data.datatable)Dts.Variables["User::DataTableVariableName"].Value;

if (dt == null)
{
   Write code to create your datatable
}
Add new DataRow to table -- lots of results on web about this and creating datatable.
```

Now you have your `datatable`. After `foreach loop` add a `script task` to move the processed files.

Again start with retrieving the table from variable

```
system.data.datatable dt = (system.data.datatable)Dts.Variables["User::DataTableVariableName"].Value;
```

then loop through `datatable` and I would suggest move the files here as well.

```
foreach (dt datarow in dt.rows)
{
  typically I like to suggest copying and then deleting the source file depending on how you over write. so you would do something like.
If (system.io.file.Exists(dr.["FileNameRowLable"].ToString())
{
   system.io.file.copy(source, destination);
   if (file.exists(destination))
   {
      file.delete(source);
   }
}
}
```

I think you will be happier sticking with moving the file in your f`oreach loop` so you wont need the script task.